# Portainer - OAuth conf. with multiple cluster nodes

Tags: google-oauth, docker-swarm, portainer

I've installed 3 nodes with Docker Swarm and Portainer:

- `node1.int.org`
- `node2.int.org`
- `node3.int.org`

Portainer uses Google Credential to authenticate each users.

The problem is that into the **Redirect URL** I can specify only one node (in the image below, `node1.int.org`). If the `node1.int.org` die, and I use `node2.int.org` or `node3.int.org` to login, the *redirect* doesn't work!

What is the best practice to solve this problem?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You create DNSRR records:
swarm.int.org A IP1
swarm.int.org A IP2
*.swarm.int.org CNAME swarm.int.org

and then use "swarm.int.org" in place of "node1.int.org" when addressing swarm hosted services.

##### Bonus Point 1

Use Traefik to handle ssl offloading, so "https://swarm.int.org" can be used to connect to Portainer on the swarm.

##### Bonus Point 2

Use keepalived or similar to allocate a pool of VIPs and map the DNSRR entries to those. This means even if nodes go down the IPs and thus DNS entries keep routing to healthy nodes.

Comment: Could I do that with NGINX `proxy_pass`?

Comment: no reason why not.

Comment: Ok, I found this: https://gdevillele.github.io/engine/swarm/networking/

Comment: I'm using `proxy_pass` in front of `node1.int.org`, `node2.int.org` and `node3.int.org` with name `node.int.org`. The `proxy_pass` works but the **Redirect URL** problem for auth remains

Comment: That document describes swarm mesh networking for how nodes talk to each other. To route traffic to a swarm, you must build similar infrastructure on the outside. You don't want all your requests to go to node1, so you need a way to load balance across node1, node2, etc. Docker can't build this for you as it is, definitionally, outside docker. You can buy load balancer devices. Create load balancers using HAProxy. Or just distribute traffic across nodes using DNSRR and make it reliable using virtual ips curtesy of keepalived.

Comment: Ok, thank you!

A recap. I built a docker swarm with 3 nodes: `node1.int.org`, `node2.int.org` and `node3.int.org`
Outside the docker swarm cluster, I can "run" a simple nginx docker with the DNS name  `node.int.org` with a round-robin `proxy_pass` to the 3 nodes.

Comment: One question again, sir.
Using an external load_balance like NGINX or HAProxy, "discovery" mode works? In others words, when I add a new node (for example `node4.int.org`) I need to update NGINX/HAProxy conf. and reload the external container?

Comment: This really needs to be a new question as its entirely unrelated to the current topic.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, following your advise I found:
- https://geek-cookbook.funkypenguin.co.nz/docker-swarm/keepalived/ 

and I've implemented a *keepalived* using Docker; It set VIP on one swarm node. I've also removed the NGINX `proxy_pass` in front.